# Doing additional operations during ActiveJDBC Model construction

Tags: java, activejdbc

I have a database with one table `words`, so my `Model` in ActiveJDBC is `Word`.

When a row from the database is casted to the `Word` model, I want to perform some additional operations, such as casting some data to enums for better abstraction.

I added a constructor to the model, which is called appropriately, but trying to access any data returns `null`. Here's the `Word` class (shortened):

```
public class Word extends Model {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Word.class);
    public static final String SPELLING = "ortho";

    public Word() {
        log.info("In constructor");
        log.info("Word spelling: " + getSpelling());
    }

    public String getSpelling() {
        return this.getString(SPELLING);
    }
}
```

but I get the following in the logs:

```
10:31:49.372 [main] INFO Word - In constructor
10:31:49.373 [main] INFO Word - Word spelling: null
```

I need to be able to cast some of these fields to enums and manipulate it in other ways to have an easier time using it.

Should I leave `Word` as an empty class such as:

```
public class Word extends Model {}
```

and have another class take it in a constructor? That would create a lot of unnecessary cruft, especially when working with `List<Word>`... what's the best way to manipulate data during `Model` object creation in ActiveJDBC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the CallbackListener or a  [CallbackAdapter](http://javalite.github.io/activejdbc/org/javalite/activejdbc/CallbackAdapter.html)

Please, see the [Lifecycle Callbacks](http://javalite.io/lifecycle_callbacks)  page.

The reason your SPELLING is `null` is because at the time of creation of the model, the attribute values are not set yet.

What you need is something like this:

```
public class Word extends Model{
   public void afterLoad(){
     String spelling = getString(SPELLING); //you have data  now
   }
}
```

Comment: Hey Igor, I had read the documentation but never saw anything related to callbacks. I use Rails, so I'm disappointed in myself for not even thinking about those! This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much! PS - I love your work on ActiveJDBC. It has made my coding much more enjoyable :)

Comment: awesome, enjoy. If you use Rails, you will feel at home with ActiveWeb too.

Comment: @ipolevoy on ActiveJDBC 1.4.11 these call backs are not being called, any idea on what could cause this behavior ?

Comment: @perrohunter, if that was the case, the test: https://github.com/javalite/activejdbc/blob/master/activejdbc/src/test/java/org/javalite/activejdbc/CallbackSupportTest.java would never pass.